# how to check and remove completely null value array from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array. I want to remove arrya if array all values are null.
I have the following array:

```
"qualifications" => array(
[0] => array(
  "qualifications" => "demo"
  "acquisition_date" => null
),
[1] => array(
  "qualifications" => null
  "acquisition_date" => null
),
[2] => array(
  "qualifications" => "test"
  "acquisition" => 123
)
);
```

I want to remove array like index[1]. 
I'm trying to the following code:

```
$educationalEmptyArray = 'false';
    if (!array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $educational))) {
        $educationalEmptyArray = 'true';
    }
```

how to unset or remove completely null value array like index[1] array.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Spholt i'm trying to 
       $educationalEmptyArray = 'false';
        if (!array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $educational))) {
            $educationalEmptyArray = 'true';
        }
but it's not working for me. this code checkd array is completely null or not but not remove compeletly null value array,

Comment: Is that readable here in the comments? Edit your question and add it there instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly the right way to do, but still works:

```
   $input = array(
        '0' => array(
        "qualifications" => "demo",
        "acquisition_date" => null
        ),
        '1' => array(
        "qualifications" => null,
        "acquisition_date" => null
        ),
        '2' => array(
        "qualifications" => "test",
        "acquisition" => 123
        )
    );
    $output = array();
    foreach($input as $array) {
        foreach($array as $key=>$value){
            if($array[$key]){
                array_push($output,$array);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The $output array completely removes null value array like index[1] array.
The above code gives the below output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [qualifications] => demo
            [acquisition_date] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [qualifications] => test
            [acquisition] => 123
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest leveraging Laravel `Collection`s for this as it makes this sort of manipulation easier. There are many, many, many ways to do this but this should do the trick

```
$collection = collect($educational)->reject(function ($items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item !== null) {
            // We have an actual value so we can safely ignore and return early
            return false;
        }
    }
    // We didn't find a non-null value, so we reject this array
    return true;
});
```

I'm not sure how eficient this will be off the top of my head